# How to vertical align a TextField in AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I´m trying to vertical align some text in a Monoline TextField in AS3.
Not sure if this can be done with TextFormat, but I don´t think so.

I´ve looked for a solution but nothing really helpful. Any help is welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can't automatically vertical align text. You need to make it by your own.

Here's my working code:

```
public static function verticalAlignTextField(tf: TextField): void {
    tf.y += Math.round((tf.height - tf.textHeight) / 2);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't moving the textfield's y move the text also?

Answer (score 6):

If you are able to use a [fl.text.TLFTextField](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/text/TLFTextField.html) instead of a `flash.text.TextField` (available from Flash Player 10+), you can vertically center the text using the verticalAlign property:

```
import flashx.textLayout.formats.VerticalAlign;
[...]
myTextField.verticalAlign = VerticalAlign.MIDDLE;
```

Answer (score 1):

i can assure that "[walkietokyo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/354167/walkietokyo)" answer  is the true answer but it should be used in the proper way see adobe documentation "([adopts default value if undefined during cascade](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/text/TLFTextField.html#verticalAlign))" in other words some properties of TLFTextFild may cascade verticalAlign properety like textFormat , so put verticalAlign property after every thing to cascade the others ,then it will workm . it works with me :)

Answer (score 1):

This works great only for the case that the text is in single line.

First you have to add an initial break line in every text. I did it in a new component extending TextField and overriding the "text" function, adding the initial break line character.

```
import flash.text.TextField;

public class MyTextField extends TextField
{
    public function MyTextField()
    {
        super();
    }

    public override function set text(value:String):void
    {
        value = "\n" + value;

        super.text = value;
    }
}
```

Then you need to apply format to the text, an use the "leading" property that represents the amount of vertical space between lines.

```
myTextFormat = new TextFormat();

// This is the existent horizontal align
myTextFormat.align = TextFormatAlign.CENTER; 

// This is my simulated vertical align. Remember that the first character 
// is always a break line. In most cases it will be a negative value...
myTextFormat.leading = -22;   

var myTextField:MyTextField = new MyTextField();
myTextField.text = "Hello";
myTextField.setTextFormat(myTextFormat);
```

I hope this will help to someone who needs vertical align in single line text using TextField. 
:-)