# how to change text vertical offset in textfield as3

Tags: actionscript-3

[image: a busy cat]

Hello.

Is there any way to discover how big is vertical offset in text field(red line, place beetween begining of text field and start of text). Can I also change it ?

Thank you for advice

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to vertical align a TextField in AS3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8452331/how-to-vertical-align-a-textfield-in-as3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to measure this distance. Maybe TextLineMetrix can help you little. Check this document:
[textLineMetrics reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextLineMetrics.html)

Also you can use textHeight property of text field.

Answer (score 0):

you can trace a comparison between the property `textHeight` and `textField.height` that may tell you the difference.

if you want to adjust it manually a work around may be in order such as creating a `Sprite` that holds the graphics of your box, or border like you have displayed, then imposing a `textField` on that which you can place by its coordinates.

Comment: This will not work because there is a space above and under the text and the difference must be divided by 2. See  TextLineMetrics reference in my post