# Bottom align TextField?

Tags: actionscript-3, textfield

So, by default, when you add text to a TextField, the text appears at the top, and works it’s way down to the bottom. I would like to do the opposite: I would like to have it appear at the bottom of the TextField, and move it’s way up to the top.

I’m using the code below and it sorta works haha. The only issue i’m having is that if the text gets longer and longer, it seems to be pushing the whole TextField down and not keeping it in the same x and y position on stage. (hope I explained that correctly).

```
var bottomCoord;
bottomCoord = myDescription_txt.y + myDescription_txt.height;
myDescription_txt.autoSize = "left";

myDescription_txt.y = bottomCoord - bottomCoord.height;
myDescription_txt.text = "Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus"
```

Anyway to do this?

Thanks! :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to vertical align a TextField in AS3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8452331/how-to-vertical-align-a-textfield-in-as3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is adjust the textfield y positioning in relation to the height as you add text to it.

Here's a SO post explaining it: [How to vertically align a TextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8452331/how-to-vertical-align-a-textfield-in-as3)

```
public static function verticalAlignTextField(tf: TextField): void {
    tf.y += Math.round((tf.height - tf.textHeight) / 2);
}
```

Comment: Ok, I still have the issue. It works perfectly if I just use in my source code - myDescription_txt.text = "Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus" - but, once I uploaded to a server and have TextField pull in the text dynamically (via xml) it's doing the same thing...  so weird!

Here is a screenshot...
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/465443/html/img_s.jpg

Comment: Are you calling the `verticalAlignTextField()` after adding your parsed XML string?

Comment: Of course, how else will it be vertically aligned if you don't call it after it's added

Comment: hmmmm... I'll have to try it, thanks! but I switched it to TLF TextField instead of Classic TextField, then I aligned it to bottom of container!  Question -  would there be any reason why I shouldn't use TLF TextField?  Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Nope that's perfectly fine.